# Define different String between platforms

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a String which represents the GameId in Unity Ads.
This GameId variable is different between iOS and Android.
Is there any way to define a global variable for this GameId which will be changed accordingly the platform which runs the game?

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html

```
public const string GameId =
#if UNITY_ANDROID
"android_game_id"
#elif UNITY_IOS
"ios_game_id"
#elif ...
...
#else ...
...
#endif
;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I saw this way and looked for a better way in the PlayerSettings. I think I will go with this implementation anyway